# Using AWS Glue data connection without Glue Data Catalog

Tags: aws-glue

it is very handy to create a shared data connection and store login/password etc. but I do not want to use glue catalog or crawler. Is it possible to use data connection just to get connection info/credentials for glue spark job and then use spark methods, bypassing Glue catalog and dynamic frames and such?

Comment: What's your input source (s3)? You can easily call spark inside glue without going through dynamic frame and glue context functions

Comment: this is what I was hoping for, thanks for your comment @Hyruma92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found much better way that does not require using boto3 and hardcoding region name:

```
    glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf('my_database_connection_name')
```

returns something like that:

```
{'enforceSSL': 'true', 'skipCustomJDBCCertValidation': 'false', 'url': 'jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx', 'customJDBCCertString': '', 'user': 'xxxx', 'customJDBCCert': '', 'password': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'vendor': 'sqlserver'}
```

Comment: Awesome find! I will actually use that myself.

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a shared connection, then you can do the following:

```
glue = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-1')
    
response = glue.get_connection(
    Name='name-of-embedded-connection',
    HidePassword=False 
)

response['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']['USERNAME']
response['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']['PASSWORD']
```